# Problem with PageSpeed Insights, question marks and "Required traces gatherer did not run" error

Tags: google-pagespeed

I'm having issue with PageSpeed Insights, when I run an audit I get question marks instead of scores, and under each metric there is an error "Required traces gatherer did not run". Here's a screenshot

[image]

The problem appears around 12:00 GMT and disappears around 21:00. Last week the issue seemed to be gone all week (no question marks and errors, the audit went fine, and scores were there), but on Friday it started again.

This problem is present on my mobile subdomain (m.mysite.com), but no errors for other subdomains and desktop version.

I ran tests of the page via Search Console when the error was appearing to check if google bot also has problem with accessing the page. The result is — the page loads fine and ready for indexing.

I also created an almost blank page without JS and CSS with only two words to check if the root of the problem may be in the scripts or CSS files. When an error began to appear I ran a test of this page and the problem remained, I also got question marks and `Required traces gatherer did not run` error.

I also found this problem once for the site https://www.gog.com/, but it was just once, now it's fine, and my site still has troubles.

Comment: Quick question: Do you get the same result if you run Lighthouse from the dev tools window of Google Chrome? Load the page in Chrome, hit F12 (or Option + ⌘ + J on Mac) and then go to the Lighthouse tab and run the report there.

Comment: No, the error appears only when I run tests through PageSpeed Insights. If I run tests in Lighthouse everything is fine, and it's fine both on Windows and Mac.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it seems that I had bloked their IP, in case you are running some ip blocker...